# Part of macro optimized away when using constant value

Tags: c, macros, avr, avr-gcc

This is a WS2812B RGB LED strip driving code for AVR (Arduino hardware). I have some issues with the compiler optimizing away parts of my code. I tried `-O1, -O2, -Os`, same result.I can't use `-O0` because then delays don't work.

## Macros

Here is my `ws_driverm.h` file:

```
#pragma once    
#include <util/delay_basic.h>
#include <avr/io.h>    
#include "lib/pins.h"

#define WS_T_1H  800
#define WS_T_1L  450
#define WS_T_0H  200
#define WS_T_0L  850
#define WS_T_LATCH 7000

/** Latch and display the RGB values */
#define ws_show(io) do { pin_low(io_pack(io)); delay_ns_c(WS_T_LATCH, 0); } while(0)

/** Send one byte to the RGB strip */
#define ws_send_byte(io, bb) do {                               \
    for (int8_t __wsba_i = 7; __wsba_i >= 0; --__wsba_i) {      \
        if (bb & (1 << __wsba_i)) {                             \
            pin_high(io_pack(io)); delay_ns_c(WS_T_1H, -2);     \
            pin_low(io_pack(io)); delay_ns_c(WS_T_1L, -10);     \
        } else {                                                \
            pin_high(io_pack(io)); delay_ns_c(WS_T_0H, -2);     \
            pin_low(io_pack(io)); delay_ns_c(WS_T_0L, -10);     \
        }                                                       \
    }                                                           \
} while(0)

/** Send RGB color to the strip */
#define ws_send_rgb(io, r, g, b) do {           \
    ws_send_byte(io_pack(io), g);               \
    ws_send_byte(io_pack(io), r);               \
    ws_send_byte(io_pack(io), b);               \
} while(0)
```

I'm not happy about it being macros, but all my attempts to use pointer to IO port, port address etc failed.

The `io` is part of my pin handling system, just ignore it, it's not relevant for the question.

## Problem

Here's the **problem** (in main)

When I use it with variables that are guaranteed to change, or mark them volatile, it works as expected:

```
volatile uint8_t r = 0;
volatile uint8_t g = 255;
volatile uint8_t b = 0;
ws_send_rgb(PIN_WS, r, g, b);
ws_show(PIN_WS);
// results in GREEN color
```

When the variables are not volatile, or if I just put numbers in the macro invocation, it does not work:

```
uint8_t r = 0;
uint8_t g = 255;
uint8_t b = 0;
ws_send_rgb(PIN_WS, r, g, b);
ws_show(PIN_WS);
// results in YELLOW color
```

Same result:

```
ws_send_rgb(PIN_WS, 0, 255, 0);
ws_show(PIN_WS);
// results in YELLOW color
```

Clearly the code produced by the macro is for some reason optimized away, if it's **constant and zero** (at least it looks that way - I'm not really sure why the LED displays yellow).

Interesting: -> If I use `1` in place of `0` for the color, it works as expected.

What is wrong with my macro, and how can I fix it?
Dirty workarounds are fine, at this point.

Comment: What is the definition of `PIN_WS` and how are defined `pin_low`, `iopack` and `delay_ns_c`?

Comment: They're some macros trickery, I'm not sure if it's a good idea to paste the whole pins.h file here. Basically, they write bits in IO port (PORTB). In essence, `pin_high(PIN_WS)` would result in `do { ((*(volatile uint8_t *)((0x05) + 0x20))) |= (1 << 0); } while(0);` after being chewed through by the preprocessor. Or, more human readable, `PORTB |= (1 << 0);`

Comment: It would be revealing to look at an assembler listing of the failing code.

Answer (score 1):

I've solved it this way for now - works pretty good:
I added `volatile` keyword to the loop variable.

No idea why it helped, but it did.

```
/** Send one byte to the RGB strip */
#define ws_send_byte(io, bb) do {                               \
    for (volatile int8_t __wsba_i = 7; __wsba_i >= 0; --__wsba_i) {      \
        if (bb & (1 << __wsba_i)) {                             \
            pin_high(io_pack(io)); delay_ns_c(WS_T_1H, -2);     \
            pin_low(io_pack(io)); delay_ns_c(WS_T_1L, -10);     \
        } else {                                                \
            pin_high(io_pack(io)); delay_ns_c(WS_T_0H, -2);     \
            pin_low(io_pack(io)); delay_ns_c(WS_T_0L, -10);     \
        }                                                       \
    }                                                           \
} while(0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing `pin_high` and `pin_low` write to a memory address.

What's happening is (in effect) the compiler is being given code like this:

```
char *address = ...;
*address = something;
*address = somethingelse;
```

It's dropping the second line there, because if `address` points to normal memory, then this does nothing. But it doesn't. Your write to memory has a side effect which is important.

In order to avoid this, you should really fix `pin_high` and `pin_low` to contain a [memory barrier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_barrier) or similar. However, your `volatile` keyword fixes it. I suspect it probably fixes it by accident, as it's really the memory address (or rather its contents) which should be `volatile`, rather than what is being written to it.

A possible route here is to introduce a C function which does nothing and hope that acts as a memory barrier (i.e. something which the compiler things might use the written value). You need this not to be optimized out. For instance:

```
static void donothingroutine() {}
volatile void (*donothing)() = &donothingroutine;
```

Then in the macro, add:

```
donothing();
```

As the pointer to the routine is declared `volatile`, from the compiler's point of view `donothing()` it *might* be a routine that accesses the 'memory' written to, so it cannot optimise out the write. So sprinkle that liberally inside your macro.

Comment: Didn't work, I added `donothingroutine();` between the two writes to the pin, same result. The written memory location is volatile, avr-libc takes care of it. It looks somewhat like `((*(volatile uint8_t *)((0x05) + 0x20))) |= (1 << 0)`

Comment: Oh! I found a fix - but it's probably not the best. If I make the loop variable in the macro volatile, it works good. Does that look like a valid solution?

Comment: I suspect you are relying on compiler heuristics. If it works for now, great (for now), but you probably need a proper memory barrier.